# Suggestion to check for unmerged imports using Pylint

Tags: python, pylint

Having used `eslint` for a few years now, one of my favorite features is [no-duplicate-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-duplicate-imports) which verifies a single import statement is being used for each module.

> Using a single import statement per module will make the code clearer
> because you can see everything being imported from that module in one
> line.

For example:

```
import { merge } from 'module';
import something from 'another-module';
import { find } from 'module';
```

Should be changed to

```
import { merge, find } from 'module';
import something from 'another-module';
```

I have searched around but cannot find such checker in Pylint. There are checkers for `import order` and `duplicate imports` as long as it is an exact match but nothing like the example above.

Another example that should be detected:

```
 from constants import CONSTANT_ONE
 from constants import CONSTANT_TWO
```

Pylint suggestion should be:

```
 from constants import CONSTANT_ONE, CONSTANT_TWO
```

How do you think we can achieve it with Pylint?

Comment: That sounds like a cool refactor checker. I suggest opening a new issue on [Pylint Official Repo on Github](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues) and ask for this new feature. You can call it disjoined-import or ununified-import or incoherent-import, or whatever you like..

Comment: There is no way (as of now) to do this with PyLint. If you are open to other answers, this can be done instead with [isort](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/), which can either automatically format your imports or just [show you a diff](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options/#show-diff) of what it would change.